# Lambda error: no module found. Cryptography.hamtaz.bindings._constant_time

Tags: python, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a lambda function which upload data to snowflake. I installed a all requirements in folder and zipped along with my main python file. While running in AWS it shows an error:

> no module found. Cryptography.hamtaz.bindings._constant_time.

But I have this module at specified path. I don't know why it shows an error. I don't know why the error is arise.

Here is the code:

```
main(event, context):
  import snowflake.connector
  cnx = snowflake.connector.connect( user='xxx', password='yyyyy', account='zzzz', database="db Name", schema = "schema Name" )
  try:
    query = "SELECT * FROM Table_Name"
    cnx.cursor().execute(query)
  finally:
    cnx.close()
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also add the steps on how you actually build your zip package, please

Comment: Created a folder and directly installed required module using pip install --target module name. Finally included the main python script and compress it into zip file.

Comment: Here is the sample code--
`def main(event, context):
    import snowflake.connector
    cnx = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user='xxx',
            password='yyyyy',
            account='zzzz',
            database="db Name",
            schema = "schema Name"
        )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced same issue recently and found it is a problem with windows environment, try to create linux environment, install Python, packages, zip your code with all libraries and then throw back to AWS lambda, hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 4):

I recently encountered the same issue.  It turned out my Lambda function runtime was Python 3.8 but the 'cffi' library had been compiled for Python 3.6.  I created a new Lambda function with the Python 3.6 runtime and uploaded my deployment package to it and it began working right away.

Answer (score 1):

i needed to set up a virtualenv for my lambda package to work.  i also found pip install snowflake-connector-python did not install some cryptography libraries, although if i navigated to the directory i wanted them to be put in, adding --target . did cause those libraries to get installed.

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.6, when I encountered the error `"Unable to import module 'main': No module named '_cffi_backend'"` in an AWS Lambda Function, I was able to run `mv _cffi_backend.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so _cffi_backend.so` in my [linux docker image](https://medium.com/i-like-big-data-and-i-cannot-lie/how-to-create-an-aws-lambda-python-3-6-deployment-package-using-docker-d0e847207dd6) with [virtualenv](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#python-package-venv) and the issue was resolved. Like mentioned above, some dependencies might be better placed with --target, to get them where you need them